# How to Retrieve two different Sharepoint list in one page

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have two lists ,list1 and list2 i want to retrieve these two list in my aspx page using javascript.i don't know to retrieve two lists.please help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use jQuery with REST API to get two list data and add to one aspx page.

Example code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var list1="list1";
    var list2="list2";
    retrieveListItems(list1).done(function(data){
        var htmlTable="<table border='1' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
        $.each(data.d.results,function(i,item){
            htmlTable+="<tr><td>"+item.Id+"</td><td>"+item.Title+"</td></tr>";
        });
        htmlTable+="</table>";
        $("#listData1").html(htmlTable);
    });
    retrieveListItems(list2).done(function(data){
        var htmlTable="<table border='1' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
        $.each(data.d.results,function(i,item){
            htmlTable+="<tr><td>"+item.Id+"</td><td>"+item.Title+"</td></tr>";
        });
        htmlTable+="</table>";
        $("#listData2").html(htmlTable);
    });
});
function retrieveListItems(listName){        
    return $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
        type: "GET",               
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    });
}
</script>
<p><div id="listData1"></div></p>
<p><div id="listData2"></div></p>
```

Comment: In This code where you retrieve the Second list .????  can you please explain

Comment: First name of the list is "list1" and second list is "list2", using retrieveListitems method to get the two list data.

Comment: Okay I Understand...Thank you so much for help me

Comment: I have one more doubt in this code....How can I retrieve data based on caml query in this code

Comment: In REST API, we can use $filter to filter the list items data.